# Alternative to web of trust

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, blocking

Are there any alternatives to web of trust for chrome and firefox. 
Because I found out that Wot doesn't always ask you if you want to access a dangerous site or not.
While I was browsing a while ago for a curriculum vitae template. I saw this image on google that looks like one. I click it but then it brought me to a site with a red mark in Wot, and wot doesn't even bother to inform me first that the site is dangerous.
Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: WOT must have paid you to close the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tired [LinkExtend](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10777) ? also there's free [McAfee SiteAdvisor](http://www.siteadvisor.com/download/ff.html),

to block miscellaneous code, you can try [NoScripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/722)

if you are aware of security, there's varities of Security related [add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/tag/security).

[this article](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/10/15/top-5-security-plugins-for-firefox-chrome-and-internet-explorer/) also may help you.